# How to store object of one class in another to access that class

Tags: c#

I'm Creating a new tool in visual studio community version 2017 with WPF technology and following MVVM architecture, I have a tree-view structure like below

```
-> Parent
    ->child
    ->child
```

Here `parent` and `child` are different classes, `parent` class contains an observable collection to hold the `child` objects. I am able to successfully add `child`-objects into that collection within the parent by selecting the parent node like `parentobj.collection.add()`, but now I have to delete the selected `child` from the collection.

I have tried to store the object of parent class in the child class when it is created but when I serialize and deserialize the code then I am unable to get the object that I have stored in child class and in the serialized file.

```
private void AddChild_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Parent InsParentViewModel = null;
    if (TreeView1.SelectedItem is Parent)
    {
        InsParentViewModel = TreeView1.SelectedItem as parent;
    }
    child newchild = new child(InsParentViewModel);
    InsParentViewModel.collection.add(newchild );
}
```

In my `child` Class I am storing the parent object as

```
class child()
{
    parent object;
    child(parent insparent)
    {
        this.object=insparent;
    }
}
```

private void AddChild_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
    {
        child newchild=null;
        if(TreeView1.SelectedItem is child)
        {
            newchild= TreeView1.SelectedItem as child;
        }

        ..........//delete here

    }
```

in this function i want to delete the child from the collection in parent.
i am selecting the chidnode from the tree-view of GUI.

Hence I would like to know how to access the object of the parent on selection of the child node.

Comment: Please share your actual code and how you serialize/deserialize your objects. It´s impossible to help you with this little information. Also add some sample-data, the expected result and what you get instead.

Comment: If your list is short enough - you may run down from the root to find a parent of selected child.

Comment: @vasily.sib actually my list varies dynamically and my Hierarchy is of level 5

Comment: How and where do you select a child-node? As `parent` is `private` within your `child`-class, you can´t access it from outside the latter.

Comment: @RobinHood425 it is not a metter of hierarchy level, but of total items count. You know a roots of your tree - just recursively run down and check which item contains deleting item as child.

Comment: @vasily.sib thank you for your suggestion it really worked